# What does this app.use() function do here:

Tags: node.js, express

I have some code from a tutorial and i am trying to understand it. I can't figure it out what's the purpose of this middleware function:

```
 app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.path = req.path;
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[res.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals) doc says:

> An object that contains response local variables scoped to the request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during that request / response cycle (if any).

This middleware sets the path part of the request URL to `res.locals` object and call next middleware.

You can use the `res.locals.path` to access the value in your controller later